# Divide results of two queries and obtain result in third query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL queries that I want to divide. On their own each query works, and I want to divide their results and obtain into third variable, but I am unsure how.

This query calculate no of cancelled members

```
(select count(*) as No_of_Member_Cancelled, M.HomeBranch,M.LocationName from 
 AX.Memberships  M
 where M.ActiveEnd between DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 
 0) and DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) ,-1)
 group by M.HomeBranch,M.LocationName) as g1
```

This query calculate the no of live members

```
(select count(*)as No_of_Live_Member , M.HomeBranch,M.LocationName
from AX.Memberships M 
where M.ActiveStart between DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 
1, 0) and DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) ,-1)
group by M.HomeBranch,M.LocationName) as g2
```

We obtain results like this

if x = g1/g2

x , LocationName , HomeBranch in one table

Comment: `select (query1) / (query2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT CAST (g1.no_of_member_cancelled AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / 
       CAST (g2.no_of_live_member AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS x, 
       g1.homebranch, 
       g1.locationname 
FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS No_of_Member_Cancelled, 
               M.homebranch, 
               M.locationname 
        FROM   ax.memberships M 
        WHERE  M.activeend BETWEEN Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, Getdate()) 
                                                  - 1, 0) 
                                   AND 
                                           Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, 
                                                          Getdate()) 
                                           , -1) 
        GROUP  BY M.homebranch, 
                  M.locationname) AS g1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Count(*)AS No_of_Live_Member, 
                          M.homebranch, 
                          M.locationname 
                   FROM   ax.memberships M 
                   WHERE  M.activestart BETWEEN Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0 
                                                               , 
                                                               Getdate()) - 1, 
                                                0) AND 
                          Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 
                                         0, Getdate( 
                                         )), -1) 
                   GROUP  BY M.homebranch, 
                             M.locationname) AS g2 
               ON g1.homebranch = g2.homebranch 
                  AND g1.locationname = g2.locationname
```

You will need to cast (or convert) your number of cancelled and live members to the datatype that fits your situation given the size of your potential values. You probably should take precaution so you don't get a division by zero error.

Comment: Can I get results in floating points? because above query only shows the whole numbers.

Comment: I added code to CAST your values to DECIMAL(10, 2). You may want to choose a different datatype based on your situation.

Comment: Can I add month(g1.ActiveStart), year(g1.ActiveStart) to show the months and years data? So we can collect for last 2 years details. As I have added code in the bottom. But its not accurate

Comment: Can you edit your question to add sample data representative of your situation and what is the result you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Best to change those to temp tables then you can do it like this:

```
select No_of_Member_Cancelled / No_of_Live_Member as x, HomeBranch, LocationName
    from G1
    join G2 on g1.HomeBranch = g2.HomeBranch and g1.LocationName = g2.LocationName
    group by HomeBranch, LocationName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT distinct CAST (g1.no_of_member_cancelled AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / 
       CAST (g2.no_of_live_member AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS x, 
       g1.homebranch, 
       g1.locationname,
       g1.month,
       g1.year 

FROM  (SELECT Count(*) AS No_of_Member_Cancelled, 
               M.homebranch, 
               M.locationname,
               month(M.ActiveStart) month,
               YEAR(M.ActiveStart) year

        FROM   ax.memberships M 
        WHERE  M.activeend BETWEEN Dateadd(year, Datediff(year, 0, Getdate()) - 2, 0)  
                                   AND 
                                   Dateadd(year, Datediff(year, 0, Getdate()), -1)
        GROUP  BY M.homebranch, 
                  M.locationname,month(M.ActiveStart),
                  year(M.ActiveStart)) AS g1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Count(*)AS No_of_Live_Member, 
                          M.homebranch, 
                          M.locationname,
                          month(M.ActiveStart) month,
                          YEAR(M.ActiveStart) year

                   FROM   ax.memberships M 
                   WHERE  M.activestart BETWEEN Dateadd(year, Datediff(year, 0, Getdate()) - 2, 0) 
                                        AND 
                                        Dateadd(year, Datediff(year, 0, Getdate()), -1)
                   GROUP  BY M.homebranch, 
                             M.locationname,
                             month(M.ActiveStart),
                             year(M.ActiveStart)
                             ) AS g2 
               ON g1.homebranch = g2.homebranch 
                  AND g1.locationname = g2.locationname
                  AND g1.month = g2.month
                  AND g1.year = g2.year
                  Order by g1.year,g1.month
```

Can you please check my query is right or not. Because I wanted to get from last 2 yrs.

Comment: What is the value of "locationname" in your memberships table? In order to help you figure this out I need sample data that is representative of your situation. Ideally, you  would provide the scripts to create the necessary table or tables and the inserts to populate them. Something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f81f20e1c5a404a6006708b7ab984314).